# php ftp_get local user

Tags: php, ftp, permissions

I'm downloading files from a remote ftp location using php `ftp_get()` function. Downloading and saving the file is done perfectly, but the file is saved on the local server with different user rights.

Looking at the files, all files uploaded by FTP get the user of the site profile. But files downloaded by a script (executed through a browser) get the user `apache`.

So at a later stage, a cronjob, who is a different user (site user) can't access these files. Because it has no permission.

So how could u I save the file using `ftp_get()` with the correct user and group?

Comment: can the cron job be given sufficient permission to access the file?

Comment: the cron job has now the user rights of the domain. I don't know who the `apache` user is and if I can run a cron script as `apache` user!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change file permissions using

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

and

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Unfortunately not possible because the `apache` user has not rights to change the rights. I came across this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225453/chown-operation-not-permitted, seems I have to deal with it!